# Java: Solving sample question for exam

Tags: java

I'm studying for a Java exam and I can't seem to solve this sample question correctly.

Suppose the method int sign(int x) returns 1 if x is positive, -1 if x is negative and 0 if x is 0. Given:

```
int[] nums = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2};
```

what are the values of the elements of nums after the following code is executed?

```
for(int k=0; k<nums.length; k++)
{
nums[k] -= sign(nums[k]);
nums[k] += sign(nums[k]);
}
```

This is a snippet of how I tried to solve it:

```
nums k -= sign (nums [k])
nums [0] = nums[0]- sign (nums[0])
nums [0] = (-2) - (0)
nums [0] = -2
```

Can someone please explain how you get to the answer: `-2, 0, 0, 0, 2.`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider for a moment the code fragment

```
n -= sign(n);
n += sign(n);
```

If `sign(n)` does not change after the fist statement, then the value of `n` will be unchanged after the fragment is executed (since you will just be adding and then subtracting the same value).

Now, when will `sign(n)` change after the first statement? If you think about it, *only* if `n` is either `1` or `-1`, in which case `n == sign(n)` and so the first statement will leave `n` at `0`. Since, `sign(0) == 0`, the second statement will have no effect if `n` is `0`. Therefore, if `n` is either `1` or `-1`, the code fragment above will result in an `n` of `0`. For all other `n`, there will be no change.

Putting it all together, what we're doing here is looping over the array and, for each element,

1. If it is either `1` or `-1`, setting it to `0`
2. Otherwise, leaving it as is.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Im new at java so it took me a few minutes to digest!

Answer (score 1):

if you follow the execution of your code step by step you will understand, this code is pretty basic...you said it yourself : if negative -1 if positive 1 otherwise 0...

do you know what is -= and += used for?